# Getting started with SolrNet in my .Net application

Tags: .net, solr, solrnet

I use Solr for couple of days and now I want to use it with my .NET application. I don't know where to start. What should I download (Solr, SolrNet, something else) ? And then how can I use it with my application, should I use .dll or NuGet Package ?
Last question, could I do the exact same thing with SolrNet and Solr ?

Answer (score 0):

SolrNet is a library that *talks to Solr*. It's not a .NET implementation of Solr.

How you decide to make the library available is up to you, but using nuget is the suggested way from the developers themselves (even if parts of the documentation [says otherwise - but the versions on nuget are identical](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/tree/master/Documentation)with the [the latest nupkg builds from their build server](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/XavierMorera/solrnet-crl26/build/artifacts) now).

For [how to use SolrNet, use the examples in the documentation](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Initialization.md).

Comment: Ok, I use nuget I think it will work but do you know if there are examples for application in VB and not C# ? Because, I can "translate" some code from a language to another but for other part I don't know how to do that (for exemple `Startup.Init<Product>("http://localhost:8983/solr");`)